# Odd behavior with AND condition in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run the query `(tags:("a"))` in elasticsearch, I get 0 results. My query URL looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/_search?q=(tags%3A(%22a%22))
```

That is to be expected, since no objects have a tag set to "a".

Now when I change the condition, and add an AND, `(org:("1") AND tags:("a"))`, **I get 3 results back**! The query URL looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/haystack/_search?q=(org%3A(%221%22)%20AND%20tags%3A(%22a%22))
```

Getting *more* results back does not make any sense to me. I would expect that kind of behavior with the OR operator, but AND? What is going on?

**Edit**: This is caused by the snowball analyzer. [See here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/t117s_pfHYw)